# Use conditional variables define at runtime with XmlCompiler

Tags: dsl, haxe, hexmachina

Quick question about [conditional parsing on hexIoC](https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexIoC#conditional-parsing).

As I know, hexIoC support DSL parsing at compile-time and runtime, with multi-pass.

Is there a solution, to use XmlCompiler with conditional variables value define at runtime?

Something like :

```
var useHlsJs:Bool = true;
#if js
useHlsJs = useHlsJs && !this.isMobile();
#end
applicationAssembler = XmlCompiler.readXmlFile( "videoplayer/configuration/context.xml", null, ["useHlsJs" => useHlsJs] );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. 
Let me explain why now.

Xml parsed by XmlCompiler generates platform code (JS, Php...) at the end, and for doing that it uses conditional variables to parse the DSL before generation.

So in a few words, it means at runtime this conditional DSL doesn't exist anymore. Your DSL has been parsed and tranformed to platform code, and all the excluded blocks by conditional variables has been removed.

```
<root name="applicationContext">
    <test if="js" id="s" value="hello JS"/>
    <test if="php" id="s" value="hello PHP"/>
</root>
```

This will generate with *-D php=true*

```
coreFactory.register( "s", "hello PHP" );
```

If you want to parse a part of your DSL with conditions at runtime, you should use XmlReader instead of XmlCompiler for this part.